# Widgets align differently in python 2.7 wrt python 2.5

Tags: python, tkinter, sticky

I have just transferred from Python 2.5 to 2.7, and I see that a GUI I created in 2.5 looks different in 2.7. I use in Tkinter the "sticky = E+W" command to stretch certain widgets
to cover the full width of my GUI. In 2.5 these widgets are automatically centered, but in 2.7 these are aligned to the left of my GUI. I can't find the command to fix this. Anybody who can help me?

Here is picture of my GUI in Python 2.5 and 2.7 (sorry I had to remove the labels as it is a GUI I created for my work..)

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-YCaW23r09gs/UDZG6TufgFI/AAAAAAAAEN8/z2_PQCxLIV8/s912/Python%25202.5%2520v%25202.7.png

Some more details about the code I use:

```
root = Tk()
root.grid()

F = Frame(root, relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 3)
F.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = EW)

Label(F,text = 'Data Source:', font = ('Arial',10)).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

LocalVar = IntVar()
CB1 = Radiobutton(F, text = 'Option 1', variable = LocalVar, value = 0, font = ('Arial',10,'italic'))
CB1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
CB2 = Radiobutton(F, text = 'Option 2', variable = LocalVar, value = 1, font = ('Arial',10,'italic'))
CB2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)  

FAQ = Button(root, bitmap = "info", width = 40, command = ShowFAQ, bg = '#0F238C', fg = 'white')
FAQ.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E)
```

Regards,
Joris

Comment: I can't reproduce using python 2.7.3 on OS-X.  The widget looks centered to me (I assume you're talking about the label). -- To be clear, would it be possible for you to post a link to screenshots (1 showing the 2.5 gui and 1 showing the 2.7 gui)?  Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: @mgilson: I have updated my question with a picture (unfortunately I was unable to add a picture as I just signed up with stackoverflow), and included more of my code. Furthermore, I am using Win7.

Comment: In the edited code, just like in the original, you don't add any weights to columns. That's at least part of the problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer; short version: this is a documented change in behavior.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I've tried using "root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 2)", but that didn't make any change. Thanks for the hint though

Comment: @Yoris: doing `columnconfigure` on the root window only affects its immediate children such as the frame; it won't affect the contents of the frame. You need to give a weight to one or more columns in the inner frame.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little research, I learned this appears to be a documented change in behavior between tk 8.4 and tk 8.5, which are the versions that python 2.5 and 2.7 use, respectively. Specifically, the behavior changed when you don't apply weights to columns.

The documentation for the change is here: http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/146.html

By the way, `root.grid()` does nothing. It's harmless but completely unnecessary.